# Nativescript-vue RadListView content moves when scrolling, breaking the layout on iOS

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue, radlistview

I'm using a RadListView in my Nativecript-Vue app. On iOS, at some point after interacting with the list view, elements start moving around and the layout breaks.

[This video shows the problem clearly](https://activix-stack-overflow.s3.amazonaws.com/video-1565634134.mp4)

I'm using an ObservableArray for my list view's data source. At first, I was expanding my list view's item on LongPress and it looked like items above the selected item were the only ones affected. I thought it could have something to do with the size of my item changing and affecting the items that were already drawn. However, if I simply scroll and fetch more data, it happens as well, so it doesn't make sense. I tried using simple tags to minimize the rendering effort, but it doesn't seem to change much.
I'm using `tns-ios v5.4.1` and `nativescript-ui-listview 7.0.2`.

Here is my RadListView declaration :

```
<RadListView ref="listView" for="item in itemList" layout="linear" loadOnDemandMode="Auto" orientation="vertical" pullToRefresh="true" swipeActions="true" :itemTemplateSelector="templateSelector" @itemSwipeProgressStarted="onSwipeStarted" @itemTap="onTap"
  @loadMoreDataRequested="onLoadMoreData" @pullToRefreshInitiated="onPullToRefresh">
  <v-template name="normal">
    <GridLayout class="px-4 bg-white border-gray-350 border-b" columns="3*, 10*, 3*">
      <AbsoluteLayout class="w-full h-full my-4" col="0">
        <activix-wrapped-icon class="p-3" width="64" height="64" background-color="bg-gray-600" icon-size="text-3xl" :icon-name="getLeadTypeIcon(item.lead_type_id)" />
      </AbsoluteLayout>

      <FlexboxLayout verticalAlignment="center" flexDirection="column" class="mx-4" col="1">
        <Label class="font-semibold" fontSize="16" :text="item.name" />

        <StackLayout class="mt-1" orientation="horizontal">
          <activix-icon name="car" />

          <Label class="ml-2" fontSize="16" :text="item.wanted_vehicle_text" />
        </StackLayout>
      </FlexboxLayout>

      <FlexboxLayout justifyContent="flex-end" verticalAlignment="center" col="2">
        <FlexboxLayout alignItems="center" justifyContent="center" height="24" width="24" class="rounded-sm" :class="getResultColor(item.result_normalized)">
          <Label class="font-bold text-white uppercase" fontSize="12" :text="getResultSymbol(item.result_normalized)" />
        </FlexboxLayout>

        <activix-icon class="ml-4 text-2xl" name="arrow-right" />
      </FlexboxLayout>
    </GridLayout>
  </v-template>
</RadListView>
```

I expect the elements of my layout to stay where they are, not move and overlap on the rest of the content when I scroll. I wanted to take advantage of the RadListView's gestures such as swipe and long press, but the basic behavior is really problematic. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you share the Playground sample where the issue can be reproduced.

Comment: Hi @Manoj, here is the [Playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=TKaxCm&v=19) where you can reproduce the issue. Tap on an item in the middle of the list and then go up. You will see how the layout reacts.

Comment: In my opinion, you are using too many of layouts / components for a simple UI. Reducing then number of layouts can greatly improve the experience. Second, you must use two different templates when you like to have expanded view, changing the number of components in the template by conditional statements is not good for iOS.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion and sorry for the delay! Following your advice, I simplified the layout a lot, but I still get the same problem. You can see what I did here : [Playground v2](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=TKaxCm&v=25). The only difference I see is that it doesn't seem to happen anymore when I simply scroll up and down for a while.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? I'm having the same issue.